# How to correctly put date in SQL form

Tags: sql

I know nothing about SQL but am trying to order a memorial keychain for someone who DOES and I'd like to put the date of their pet's passing in SQL form ... Is this correct?

```
SELECT DATE("2019-11-05");
```

Comment: When it comes to date/time, many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. Which dbms are you using?

Comment: ANSI SQL has `DATE'2019-11-05'`.

Comment: Oh, no, I apologize for not communicating this correctly. - I'm just putting it as text on a keychain. (Trying to be creative for someone who enjoys coding.)

Comment: I see, then you should ask your friend which dbms he/she is used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the database.  In general, date and string constants should use single quotes.  The SQL standard for a date literal is:

```
SELECT DATE '2019-11-05'
```

However, databases might also prefer:

```
SELECT DATE('2019-11-05')
SELECT CAST('2019-11-05' as DATE)
```

Or perhaps something else.